# My flutter code can't find a list of available MIDI devices

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm doing a project to develop an app that automatically turns the sheet music.

So, what I'm trying to do is first, export a list of available MIDI devices and it actually has no errors with this code. Still, it doesn't seem that it can actually find out the MIDI device even though I connected to my laptop with my lightning-USB cable perfectly.

I would be pleased if someone gives me any advice or solutions. :)

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_midi_command/flutter_midi_command.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Midi Input Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Midi Input Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> deviceNames = [];
  List<String> deviceIds = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bringMidiDevice();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                bringMidiDevice();
              });
            },
            child: const Text("새로고침"),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: deviceNames.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(deviceNames[index]),
                  subtitle: Text(deviceIds[index]),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          if (deviceNames.isEmpty)
            const Center(
              child: Text("None"),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> bringMidiDevice() async {
    // Calls MIDI devices
    List<MidiDevice>? devices = await MidiCommand().devices;

    // Saving MidiDevice's name and id with a List<String> format
    deviceNames = devices?.map((device) => device.name).toList() ?? [];
    deviceIds = devices?.map((device) => device.id).toList() ?? [];
  }
}
```